# Rendering component on long mouse click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to render a modal component on a long mouse click. If I just try to fire an alert it works but rendering doesn't seem to do the trick. I am assuming maybe If I have to return? Not quite sure. I created a function `handleButtonPressDown` to perform this task and the `handleButtonRelease` to clear interval in the event the user decides not to perform this action.

```
export class Dropdown extends React.Component<IProps> {
  buttonPressTimer: any;
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
    this.handleButtonPress = this.handleButtonPress.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonRelease = this.handleButtonRelease.bind(this);
  }

  public render() {

    return (
      <div style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
        <ul className="nav nav-pills">
          {filteredProbes.length === 0 ? (
            <li className="nav-item dropdown ">
              <div
                className="dropdown-menu show"
                x-placement="bottom-start"
                style={{
                  display: "none"
                }}
              ></div>
            </li>
          ) : (
            <li className="nav-item dropdown ">
              <div
                className="dropdown-menu show"
                x-placement="bottom-start"
                style={{
                  position: "relative",
                  willChange: "transform",
                  top: "5px",
                  overflowY: "scroll",
                  maxHeight: "200px",
                  color: "white"
                }}
              >
                {this.props.searchState.isActive === false
                  ? probes.map(probe => (
                      <a
                        onClick={() => this.props.onUpdateSelectedProbe(probe)}
                        className="dropdown-item"
                        onMouseDown={this.handleButtonPress}
                        onMouseUp={this.handleButtonRelease}
                      >
                        <div
                          className="dropdown-divider"
                          style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}
                        ></div>
                        {probe.companyPN}: {probe.description}
                      </a>
                    ))
                  : filteredProbes.map(filterprobe => (
                      <a
                        onClick={() =>
                          this.props.onUpdateSelectedProbe(filterprobe)
                        }
                        className="dropdown-item"
                      >
                        <div className="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        {filterprobe.companyPN}: {filterprobe.description}
                      </a>
                    ))}
              </div>
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleButtonPress() {
    this.buttonPressTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      {/* Show the modal if showModal is true */}
      this.props.modalState.showModal && (
        <WedgeGroup
          wedgeState={this.props.wedgeState}
          onUpdateSelectedWedge={this.props.onUpdateSelectedWedge}
          onUpdateShowModal={this.props.onUpdateShowModal}
          onUpdateHideModal={this.props.onUpdateHideModal}
          modalState={this.props.modalState}
        />
      );
    }, 1000);
  }
  handleButtonRelease() {
    clearTimeout(this.buttonPressTimer);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the code that you have inside `setTimeout` to `render` function and use `state` to render `WedgeGroup`:

```
export class Dropdown extends React.Component<IProps> {
    ...
    constructor(props: IProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showModal: false
        };
        ...
    }

    public render() {
        const showModal = this.props.modalState.showModal &&
            this.state.showModal;

        return (
            <div style={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
                {
                    showModal && (
                        <WedgeGroup
                            wedgeState={this.props.wedgeState}
                            onUpdateSelectedWedge={this.props.onUpdateSelectedWedge}
                            onUpdateShowModal={this.props.onUpdateShowModal}
                            onUpdateHideModal={this.props.onUpdateHideModal}
                            modalState={this.props.modalState}
                        />
                    );
                }

                //..... render other components
            </div>
        );
    }

    handleButtonPress() {
        this.buttonPressTimer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                showModal: true
            })
        }, 1000);
    }
    handleButtonRelease() {
        clearTimeout(this.buttonPressTimer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not render firstly because your are not triggering any mechanism that makes React render.
I'd suggest to you to remove this component from the setTimeout, place it inside the render (where it should be).
And finally manipulate your component state to show or hide your modal.
If you trigger a timer to show the modal view it will only appear after the change of the state, so in your case it will take 1s to show to the user, what may look not responsive.

```
// inside your handleButtonPress()
this.setState({
    showModal: true
}}
```

Comment: What would be the more responsive time for the user?

Comment: There is this great [article](https://medium.com/@slhenty/ui-response-times-acec744f3157).